# Running simulations and extracting data from Blender for analysis

Tags: python, rigid-body-simulation

Suppose I want to build a scene in Blender where many balls collide. Once everything has settled, I want to find out if a particular ball has rolled outside the circle, where the collisions occurred. I have a couple of questions in that regard:

A) How can I extract data from Blender to learn if the ball has left the circle?
B) How can I vary the initial conditions of the scene slightly and simulate many instances of the scene to discover the relative frequency with which the particular ball leaves the circle?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question, and I would love to see what you come up with. I just spent some time trying to figure out A). I've looked before without luck, but today I discovered the object matrix_local contains the current translation matrix of an object. That means you can do this to find out the location, rotation, and scale:

```python
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

loc, rot, sca =  D.objects['Sphere'].matrix_local.decompose()
print('Location:', loc, '\nRotation:', rot, '\nScale:', sca)
```

You can find distance from the origin with:

```
loc.magnitude
```

And finally:

```
 (Vector( (1,1,1) ) - loc).magnitude
```

gives the distance from the point (1,1,1).

See the [docs on Blender Matrix and Vector types](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html) and [this answer on accessing matrix elements](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/189460/33589)

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Basic Game]

So this is my attempt to answer your B). This is a complete Blender scene entirely created in Python. It features 16 balls that collide around a table, the initial impulse to get everything started is a key-framed stick. All the balls and bumpers are created in a loop, so its easy to change their physics properties. The position of the 15 colored balls is tightly packed, but multiplying the location vectors by a value slightly larger than 1 will allow looser packs. Random numbers are possible, too, even though I did not explore them here.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Color
from math import radians
import numpy as np

if bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world:
    print('Rigid Body World Found')
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_remove()
    
bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add()
bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.collection = bpy.data.collections.new('Pool Game')

triangle = [Vector( ( 0, -20, 0.5 ) ),]

balls = []

ball_color = [ 
  ( 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1),## 0 is white
  ( 0.9, 0.8, 0.0, 1),## 1 is yellow
  ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 1),## 2 is blue
  ( 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 1),## 3 is red
  ( 0.4, 0.0, 0.8, 1),## 4 is purple
  ( 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 1),## 5 is orange
  ( 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 1),## 6 is green
  ( 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1),## 7 is burgundy
  ( 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 1),## 8 is black
  ( 0.9, 0.8, 0.0, 1),## 9 is yellow
  ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 1),## 10 is blue
  ( 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 1),## 11 is red
  ( 0.4, 0.0, 0.8, 1),## 12 is purple
  ( 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 1),## 13 is orange
  ( 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 1),## 14 is green
  ( 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 1),## 15 is burgundy
]

slate_color = ( 0.21, 0.47, 0.15, 1)
felt = bpy.data.materials.new('Felt')
felt.diffuse_color = slate_color

root3o2 = np.sqrt(3)/2

for row in range(5):
    for col in range(row + 1):
        triangle.append( Vector( (row/2 - col, row*root3o2, 0.5) ) )

i=0
for loc, col in zip(triangle, ball_color):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(segments=32, 
        ring_count=16, radius=0.5, calc_uvs=True, 
        enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', 
        location=loc, rotation=(0, 0, 0))
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
    ball = bpy.context.object
    balls.append( ball ) # grab a reference to each ball as it is created.
    ball.active_material = bpy.data.materials.new('BallMat')
    ball.active_material.diffuse_color = ball_color[i]
    ball.active_material.roughness = 0.1
    bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].rigidbody_world.collection.objects.link(ball)
    ball.rigid_body.collision_shape = 'SPHERE'
    ball.rigid_body.restitution = 0.9 # Bounciness
    ball.rigid_body.friction = 0.2
    
    
    i += 1
    
# make the slate:
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, -10, -0.05))
slate = bpy.context.object
slate.scale = (10,20,0.05)
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)
slate.active_material = felt
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].rigidbody_world.collection.objects.link(slate)
slate.rigid_body.type='PASSIVE'
slate.rigid_body.friction = 0.3
slate.rigid_body.restitution = 0.8


#make the bumpers
bumper_locations = [
    (  0,-30, 0.5),
    (  0, 10, 0.5),
    ( 10,  0, 0.5),
    (-10,  0, 0.5),
    ( 10,-20, 0.5),
    (-10,-20, 0.5),
]

bumper_rotations = [
    ( radians(45), 0, 0),
    ( radians(45), 0, 0),
    ( radians(45), 0, radians(90) ),
    ( radians(45), 0, radians(90) ),
    ( radians(45), 0, radians(90) ),
    ( radians(45), 0, radians(90) ),
]

bumper_scale = (18, .707, .707)

for loc, rot in zip(bumper_locations, bumper_rotations):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=loc )
    bumper=bpy.context.object
    bumper.scale = bumper_scale
    bumper.rotation_euler = rot 
    bumper.active_material = felt
    bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].rigidbody_world.collection.objects.link(bumper)
    bumper.rigid_body.type='PASSIVE'
    bumper.rigid_body.restitution = 0.7 # Bounciness
    bumper.rigid_body.friction = 0.3

# finally the Cue
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=32, radius=0.1, depth=5, end_fill_type='TRIFAN',
    calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(radians(90), 0, 0))
cue = bpy.context.object
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].rigidbody_world.collection.objects.link(cue)
cue.rigid_body.type='ACTIVE'
cue.rigid_body.kinematic = True
cue.rigid_body.restitution = 0.7 # Bounciness
cue.rigid_body.friction = 0.8
cue.rigid_body.collision_margin = 0.1
cue.location = (0, -25, 0.5)
cue.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=1)
cue.location = (0, -10, 0.5)
cue.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=13)
cue.location = (0, -10, 5)
cue.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=21)
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_current = 1
```